# Сортировка списка по первому элементу

Tags: python

Дан вложенный список, содержащий целые числа. Необходимо отсортировать все строки списка с помощью заданного ключа, а затем переставить строки таким образом, чтобы первые элементы были отсортированы с помощью заданного ключа в обратном порядке. Ключ key передается в функцию.

```
data = [[1], [3, 2], [6, 5, 4]]
key = lambda x: x
res = [[4, 5, 6], [2, 3], [1]]
```

Comment: `res = [sorted(i) for i in reversed(data)]`

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/python-sorting/

Comment: "переставить строки таким образом, чтобы первые элементы были отсортированы с помощью заданного ключа в обратном порядке" вот это как сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать:

```
new_data1 = [sorted(i, key=key) for i in data] # сортировка внутренних списков 
new_data2 = sorted(new_data1, key=key, reverse=True) # сортировка главного списка
```

В одну строку можно так:

```
new_data = sorted([sorted(i, key=key) for i in data], key=key, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Ошибка в строке new_data2 = sorted(new_data1, key=key, reverse=True)

Comment: @Dan_27 какая ошибка

Comment: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'

Comment: @Dan_27 нет в моем коде такой ошибки

Comment: Если вызвать функцию def sorted2(data, key=lambda x: -x):
    new_data1 = [sorted(i, key=key) for i in data]
    new_data2 = sorted(new_data1, reverse=True)
    return new_data2,  data = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]], print(sorted2(data))

Comment: @Dan_27 в моем ответе нет функции sorted2, так что я тут не причём

Comment: Так код не работает, если вызвать просто для списка data = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]], print(data)

Comment: @Dan_27 вы используете `key= lambda x: -x`, а вопросе `key=lambda x : x`

Comment: Там ключ передается в функцию, необязательно key=lambda x : x